# How can I use PyQt4 "considering QtGui.QPainter" through procedural programming?

Tags: qt, python-2.7, user-interface, pyqt4

as I am moving from `tkinter` to `PyQt4` and I don't like **OOP** that much.
in `tkinter` you can actually set your *window* , *buttons* , *entrybox* ,...etc using **procedural programming**
when I tried to do the same ,I just could create the GUI but couldn't do any actual work out of it.. why this code doesn't work as it's supposed to ??!
I have another version of it using **OOP** and it works fine but I'm not a big fan of **OOP** plus I really want to know why I can't get `PyQt4` to work using **procedural programming**
here is the code :-

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore  
import sys 

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)  

widget = QtGui.QWidget()  
widget.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)  
widget.setWindowTitle('draw')  

bt=QtGui.QPushButton('qyuit',widget)  ##create the button  

paint = QtGui.QPainter(widget)  ## create "paint" object enables me to draw

def draw_line():
    print 'start draw line'

    paint.begin(widget)

    pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 20, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
    pen.setCapStyle(QtCore.Qt.RoundCap)        
    pen.setJoinStyle(QtCore.Qt.RoundJoin)  

    paint.setPen(pen)

    paint.drawLine(30, 70, 250, 90) ## drawing the line

    paint.end()
    widget.update()  

bt.clicked.connect(draw_line) ## connecting the clicked event with "draw_line" method


widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So when I press the button , there is no line drawn.. It just prints the 'start draw line' in python shell .. Why this line can't be drawn ??!
Thanks in advance .

Comment: I would also like to know. Anyone?